# xcode update app files on an existing folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my current iOS application I created a ResourceDoc folder that contains some initial content files. Then, app checks if is any update for that files on a server, and if yes, I need to download it and save it instead of existing ones. Possibly is a basic issue but how to store files to ResourceDoc folder? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update resources. They're read-only. You'd have to create a parallel directory and check there first before loading from the standard location.

That is, assuming you added these as resources to your Xcode project ...